# basic looping in Python

Tags: python

New to this so please bear with me. I'm trying to run a loop that asks the user to input a number between 1 and 100. I want to make it to where if they enter a number outside of 100 it asks again. I was able to do so but I can't figure out if I'm using the correct loop. Also whenever I do get inbetween 1 and 100 the loop continues.

code below:

```
user_input = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100: "))
if user_input >= 1 and user_input <= 100:
    print("NICE!")
else: 
    while user_input > 100:
        try_again = int(input("try again "))
        if try_again >= 1 and try_again <= 100:
            print("There you go!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the clearest way to do this is to start with a loop that you break out of when you finally get the right answer. Be sure to handle a bad input like "fubar" that isn't an integer

```
while True:
    try:
        user_input = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100: "))
        if user_input >= 1 and user_input <= 100:
            print("NICE!")
            break
        print("Not between 1 and 100, try again")
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a number, try again")
```

In python 3 you can use `range` to do bounds checking. If you do

```
        if user_input in range(1, 101)
```

`range` will calculate the result without actually generating all of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

When your code is run, it will continue to ask for an input, even if the input given is less than 100. One way to fix this would be to do this:

```
try_again = 1000
user_input = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100: "))
if user_input >= 1 and user_input <= 100:
    print("NICE!")
elif user_input > 100:
        while try_again > 100:
        try_again = int(input("try again "))
        if try_again >= 1 and try_again <= 100:
            print("There you go!")
```

This code first tests if the user's input is more than 100, then runs a while statement in which the base value is more than 100. When the user inputs another value, if it is over 100, it continues, otherwise it does not.

Comment: oh ok thanks. Yeah I looked on the web but I was just looking for feedback from my code I came up with. Thanks!

Comment: oh but also, say the user keeps inputting a number higher than 100... what's a good way to ask for them to "Try Again" until they get it? instead of running the code again

Comment: I don't see how the `elif` prompts the user again.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking you had a different point, I will revise my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Tdelaney... that helped a lot!

Comment: There, that should be better.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of a program that gets you the output that you are seeking:

```
attempts = 0

while True:
     user_input = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 100: "))

     if user_input > 100 or user_input < 1:
          print('Please try again')
          attempts += 1
          continue
     elif attempts >= 1 and user_input <= 100 and user_input >= 1:
          print('There you go!')
          break
     else:
          print('Nice!')
          break
```

Start by putting your prompt for the user within the loop so that the user can be asked the same prompt if the fail to enter a number between 1 and 100 the first time. If the user input is greater than 100 or less than 1, we will tell the user to try again, we will add 1 to attempts and we will add a continue statement which starts the code again at the top of the while loop. Next we add an elif statement. If they've already attempted the prompt and failed (attempts >= 1) and if the new input is less than or equal to 100 AND the user input is also greater than or equal to 1, then the user will get the 'There you go' message that you assigned to them. Then we will break out of the loop with a break statement in order to avoid an infinite loop. Lastly we add an else statement. If the user satisfies the prior conditions on the first attempt, we will print 'Nice' and simply break out of the loop.